# Redirecting to HTML from PHP with setting img src

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to HTML and PHP. I am designing a html page which invokes a php for some computation. In the end the php function returns a src path. I want to invoke the initial html page with a pre-existing img tag, and I want to set the src of the img tag to be the src url contained in the php function.

I am using the

```
echo
'<script>',
'<a href="Age.html"><img id= "preview" name= "preview" src=' + $src_path + '/></a>;',
'</script>';
```

src_path = http://localhost:8082/AgePage/uploads/case.jpg, which I am able to check through echo.
But it is not redirecting to the Age.html page. If I do simply :

```
echo
'<script>',
'window.location.href = "http://localhost:8082/AgePage/Age.html";',
'</script>';
```

It redirects to Age.html page.

Please help. The code snippet will be great.
Thank you

Comment: You're actually putting your image into javascript, it cannot work. Seperate javascript and html

Comment: Use `$_GET` in `PHP` to set the new URL **or** use `JavaScript`.

Comment: Can you please send me the code snippet ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to seperate javascript and HTML like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <?php
           echo '<a href="Age.html"><img id= "preview" name= "preview" src="' . $src_path . '"/></a>';
        ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note that if you want to do a plain redirection in PHP (without putting the link on your image but just do it manually) you don't have to do a Javascript redirection (and you should not because user can turn off javascript on their browser). You can do it in php:

```
   <?php 
     header('Location: '.$your_url);
   ?>
```

*** UPDATE ***********

PHP file:

```
<?php 
     //This will set a cookie for 1 hour named imageToOutput, change $path for the path you want to set
     $path = '/my/file/path.png';
     setcookie("imageToOutpout", $path, time()+3600);
     header('Location: home.html');
?>
```

Then, in your home.html

```
 <html>
    <body>
       <a href="Age.html"><img src="<= $_COOKIE['imageToOutput'] ?>" name="preview" /></a>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Note that the `<?= ?>` is the same as doing [echo](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.echo.php) in PHP

Comment: Good. I would add double quotes around the `src` attribute value.

Comment: I want to redirect to home.html from my php file, and on the redirected html page I want to set the image src.

Comment: Hold on i'll write it for you

Comment: I tried- echo '<a href="Age.html"><img id= "preview" name= "preview" src="' + $src_path + '"/></a>';----It echoed 0, and didn't redirect.

Comment: The updated solution only redirects to Age.html page, without setting the img src.

Comment: You have to set the cookie properly in your php file that redirect to home.html in order to make this work. the $path variable has to be your image path in the updated solution.